# How to show that the time complexity of algorithm is O(2^n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'am doing a practice interview question from [HackerRank Coin Change](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change)

I got stuck and I'm trying to understand a [Solution](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-coin-change-problem/) to this problem. Here is the recursive solution to this problem.(with my comments to understand it)

```
  public static int numWays(int[] coins, int sumTo) {
   return numWaysWhichCoin(coins, sumTo, 0);
}
private static int numWaysWhichCoin(int[] coins, int sumTo, int whichCoin) {
    if(sumTo == 0) {
        //empty set
        return 1;
    } else if(sumTo < 0) {
        //no way to form a negative sum with positive coin values
        return 0;
    }  else {
        //sumTo is positive 
        //case gone through all the coins but still a positive sum. Impossible
        if(sumTo > 0 && whichCoin == coins.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        //with and without. With, you can keep using the same coin 
        return numWaysWhichCoin(coins, sumTo - coins[whichCoin], whichCoin) + numWaysWhichCoin(coins, sumTo, whichCoin + 1);
    }
}
```

The author states that the algorithm runs in O(2<sup>n</sup>) time complexity. From my experience in interviews, you are expected to justify your answers.

How wold you justify this time complexity? From my previous work to showing algorithms run in O(2<sup>n</sup>) time, I would use recurrence relations, like(Fibonacci) T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +c <= 2T(n-1) + c, 
T(1) = d, but I can't derive a recurrence relation like that from here. Is there another way of going about this justification?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What about gen-y-s's solution?

Comment: That analysis gives the bound O((2^n)^(#coins)), which is usually quite an overestimate.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat But anyways how were you able to tell that this runs in O(2^n)) time algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

The two recursive calls make it act like a binaric tree that grows in 2 n rate.

Your algorithm as far as complexity is identical to Fibonacci recursive algorithem. So you can look and find the many answers and explenations and even proofs why recursive Fibonacci is from the order of 2 n.

Comment: I know the Fibonacci proof. Its T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + d <= 2T(n-1) + d which was what I was referring to. But here I couldn't find a recurrence relation that bounded this algorithm.

Comment: The return statement at the bottom of your code is practically the same. The last parameter is  n for this matter

Comment: yea thanks. They prob won't be that strict. I just say that this is similar to the two recursive calls pattern in Fibonacci and give that proof if necessary.

Comment: Maybe you can add the other parameters and then dissmis them as constants that do not affect the big O notation? I am not sure if you can do that

Comment: Not sure about that. In Fibonacci, n-1 and n-2 weren't constants(dependent on n). I just say the patterns are similar with regards to the runtime. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think whichCoin is n in this case. That is pretty clear.

Comment: but sumTo is also a variable, which makes it a candidate for n

Comment: But big O notation is the worst case so you need to show that even in the best case of your code you will still have 2 n so you can asuume first two parameters to be 1 and still have 2 n order.

Comment: Not getting what you're saying. If I assume the first two parameters to be 1, then both of those function calls will run in constant time, meaning the function itself will run in constant time.

Comment: there are three parameters in every call so it will converge to the same as Fibonacci

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are R different combinations (the requested result).
The number of coins of the i-th coin (0<=i<=M-1) used in a specific solution r (0<=r<=R-1) is C(i, r). So for each r in 0...R-1 we have C(0,r)+C(1,r)+....C(M-1,r)=N.
The maximum value of C(i, r) for each r in 0...R-1 is max_c(i)=floor(N/Vi) (Vi is the value of coin i), which less or equal to N.
The sum of c_max(i) where i=0..M-1 is <= N*M.  So the total number of individual coins used in all the combinations is O(NM). 
The algorithm you presented simply iterates all the sub-groups of the group above of c_max(i) individual coins for each coin value Vi, which O(2^(NM)).

Comment: I am a bit confused by the notation you're using. With regards to C(0,r), from https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html , doesn't that mean to choose r things from nothing?

Comment: r is an arbitrary enumeration of the possible combinations (sequences) to make the change.  For example with coins 1,2,3 and sum of 4, the combinations are  (4,0,0),  (3,0,1), (2,1,0), (0,2,0),  so I just enumerate these 4 combinations  as 0..3. So for the first combination r=0 we have C(0,0)=4, C(1,0)=0, C(2,0)=0.